# ConcurrentModificationException in a Java game

Tags: exception, set, game-engine

I am at the early stages of developing a 2d shooter game (Picture Metal Slug) using JAVA. I want to be able to shoot many bullets at the time. In order to do so i use a Set to control the current bullets on the screen, each time you click you spam a bullet, adding it to the screen and to the set of bullets (so in each frame, you move each bullet in the set according to their speed).

My problem is that if I click fast enough I get an 
      ConcurrentModificationException

Is there a data structure able to add and remove fast enough different objects without getting such exception? I can not find any that suit me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure able to suit your requirements is a ConcurrentHashMap, check:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html